# Access Methods outside MouseListener

Tags: java, mouselistener

I am doing a simple JTable, and I created a mouselistener to respond when I double click on the table (depending on the index). I all works fine, the problem is that I can't call methods that are outside my mouselistener. Here is the code:

```
public class PendingAction extends AccountAbstractAction{

    private class TransferTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2497950520925208080L;

        private List<Transfer> transfers;

        public TransferTableModel(List<Transfer> transfers) {
            this.transfers = new ArrayList<>(transfers);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            String key = null;
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                key = "account.number";
                break;
            case 1:
                key = "destination.account.number";
                break;
            case 2:
                key = "amount";
                break;
            default:
                assert false;
                break;
            }
            return textManager.getText(key);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return transfers.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Transfer t = transfers.get(rowIndex);
            Object val = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                val = t.getAccount().getId().getNumber();
                break;
            case 1:
                val = t.getDestinationAccount().getId().getNumber();
                break;
            case 2:
                val = t.getAmount();
                break;
            default:
                assert false;
                break;
            }
            return val;
        }

    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5090183202921964451L;

    private JDialog dialog;
    private JTable transfers;

    public PendingAction (BankGraphicInterface bankInterface,
            TextManager textManager,
            AccountOperationService accountOperationService){
        super(bankInterface, textManager, accountOperationService);

        super.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        super.putValue(Action.NAME, textManager.getText("action.pending"));
    }

    public void close() {
        dialog.dispose();
        dialog = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JPanel transactionsPanel = new JPanel();
        transactionsPanel
                .setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        transfers = new JTable();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(transfers,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        transactionsPanel.add(scrollPane);

        showPending();

        transfers.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                JTable table =(JTable) me.getSource();
                Point p = me.getPoint();
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
                if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    Object[] options = { "ACEITAR", "RECUSAR", "FECHAR" };
                    int optionSelected = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Aceitar transferência pendente?", "Pendente", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                    switch(optionSelected) {
                    case 0:
                        this.acceptPending(row);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.rejectPending(row);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            private void rejectPending(int row) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            // HERE IS THE ERROR
            // .................
            // I try to access this.transfer (outside Mouse Listener)
            // but I get an error trying to do this
            private void acceptPending(int row) {
                Object accountOrigin = this.transfers.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                Object accountDestin = this.transfers.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
                Object ammount       = this.transfers.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);

                int intAccountOrigin;
                int intAccountDestin;

                try {
                    intAccountOrigin = (int) accountOrigin;
                    intAccountDestin = (int) accountDestin;


                } catch (ClassCastException exc) {

                }   
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(transactionsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.dialog = GUIUtils.INSTANCE.createDialog(bankInterface.getFrame(),
                "action.pending", pane);
        this.dialog.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void showPending() {
        try {
            List<Transfer> transfers = accountOperationService.getPending();
            this.transfers.setModel(new TransferTableModel(transfers));
        } catch (BusinessException be) {
            GUIUtils.INSTANCE.showMessage(bankInterface.getFrame(),
                    be.getMessage(), be.getArgs(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            log.warn(be);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            GUIUtils.INSTANCE.handleUnexceptedError(bankInterface.getFrame(),
                    exc);
        }
    }

}
```

I highlighted on the code the part that is giving me trouble.
Basically I don't know how to access methods or attributes from a class outside of MouseListener.

Comment: You're actually trying to access something **inside** of your MouseListener, not outside of it. Your code worries me in that there's a lot of nesting of classes which suggests that it might be best to try to refactor some of it.

Comment: Yes, I now moved those classes outside the mouse listener, so it is a lot better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TransferTableModel.this` instead of `this`.

In inner class, the `this` is for the current inner class instance. To access to a container instance, you should use the `.this` property of the container class itself.